admob banner ad android studio disappear after one day
I inserted a banner ad (admob) into my game on Android Studio, and when I testing it on my phone (loading the apk file into the phone) works correctly. The problem is that when I reopen the game the next day (and not updating and redownloading it again) the advertising disappears and it doesn't load. The same thing also applies to the interstitial ad that I inserted (both in the mainActivity). Is this a problem that solves itself when I load the game on the play store and i connect it with my admob account, or it's the code? Can someone help me? Thank you!
Here is the code:
"MAINACTIVITY"
new Thread(
                () -> {
                    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK on a background thread.
                    MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {});
                })
                .start();

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

"XML mainActivity"
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx" />

The ad has to be always in the game. I tried setting the visibility of the banner on "VISIBLE" but it doesnt change anything.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
